# Creating MSI installer with netbeans IDE 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans, wix

When I try to create msi installer using netbeans IDE it showed following error:[image: cannot run program candle]

I have installed wix 3.8 and added "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin" to my path. still IDE shows following error:[image: wix not installed or not in path]

How can I solve the issue and create a msi installer for my javaFX app? Anyone please help.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the output of the candle.exe -? command is no longer match the Ant Targets -check-WiX-presence

```
<target name="-check-WiX-presence" depends="-check-native-bundling-type" if="need.WiX.presence">
    <local name="exec-output"/>
    <local name="exec-error"/>
    <local name="exec-result"/>
    <exec executable="candle" outputproperty="exec-output" failifexecutionfails="false" errorproperty="exec-error" resultproperty="exec-result">
        <arg value="-?"/>
    </exec>
    <echo message="exec-output:${exec-output}" level="verbose"/>
    <echo message="exec-error:${exec-error}" level="verbose"/>
    <echo message="exec-result:${exec-result}" level="verbose"/>
    <condition property="missing.WiX">
        <not><and>
            <contains string="${exec-output}" substring="Windows Installer Xml Compiler"/>
            <not><contains string="${exec-output}" substring="Windows Installer Xml Compiler version 1"/></not>
            <not><contains string="${exec-output}" substring="Windows Installer Xml Compiler version 2"/></not>
        </and></not>
    </condition>
</target>
```

This is what WiX 3.8 output:
Windows Installer XML Toolset Compiler version 3.8.1128.0
Copyright (c) Outercurve Foundation. All rights reserved.

So fixing the condition to

```
<contains string="${exec-output}" substring="Windows Installer XML Toolset Compiler"/>
```

in build-native.xml will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following line also works fine.

```html
<contains string="${exec-output}" substring="Windows Installer XML" casesensitive="false"/>
```